# How to place a JToolBar at the bottom of my JFrame (like a MS visual component)?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a Swing MDI application, with many JInternalFrames and all. Now I want to create a JToolBar and place it at the bottom of the main JFrame (like a MS visual component)?

What would be the best implementation?

I'm trying like this, but it ins't visually a good approach:

```
jDesktopPane.add(jToolBar1);
jToolBar1.setSize(new Dimension(?, ?));
jToolBar1.setLocation(?, ?);
```

Comment: Place the took bar on the same container as the `JDesktopPane`, using a `BorderLayout`, you can place it at the `SOUTH` position

Answer (score 1):

You can use the borderLayout class:
this is an example from : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.applet.Applet;

 public class buttonDir extends Applet {
   public void init() {
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     add(new Button("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
     add(new Button("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     add(new Button("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
     add(new Button("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
     add(new Button("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using AWT based components for a Swing based question?